# Restriction of url parameters in asp.net

Tags: url, asp.net-3.5

I have updated a website i have made recently, using asp.net. The problem Im now encountering is this. If I send in the request parameters of a page: i.e.
www.something.com/index.aspx?search=vendor, this url leads to a page stating "Command cannot execute". It used to work fine in my old version, and im still using the same iis server and the same database.

I have narrowed it down to note that if the word "vend" is found in the url it gives this error. I suspect this restriction is made in the asp.net project? If yes, how can I remove it. My users need to be able to send requests containing these letters.

Comment: Please post the code that throws the exception

Comment: It doesnt even enter the code to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but you might want to check the routing if there is any.

Comment: Can I ask you what you mean by the routing?

Comment: She is using asp.net, not MVC. Since she did not mention any routing, it seems very unlikely, that this is the issue. Given the exception message I'd assume it's a DB issue, but we need to see some code in order to verify this.

Comment: The problem is the db is still the same as before and when i debug locally it doesnt even enter the page in the url, so it doesnt seem to be a code issue. I simply get a blank page with the words "Cannot execute command".